# attr_encryptor gem fails only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, heroku

I'm using the [attr_encryptor](https://github.com/danpal/attr_encryptor) gem in my app. It works without a hitch in development but fails on production (Heroku). The error I get is:

> Mysql2::Error: Field 'encrypted_ssn' doesn't have a default value

This tells me that attr_encryptor is somehow not even trying to insert the encrypted value into the database. Here's my model code:

```
class MerchantProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user
  validates :phone, presence: true, format: /\A[\(\)0-9\- \+\.]{10,20}\z/
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true
  validates :ssn, presence: true, format: /\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}/
  validates :account_number, presence: true
  validates :routing_number, presence: true
  before_validation :check_sensitive_fields

  SENSITIVE_ATTRIBUTES = %i(ssn account_number routing_number)
  SENSITIVE_ATTRIBUTES.each { |attr| attr_encryptor attr, key: Rails.configuration.database_field_encryption_key }

  def init
    self.date_of_birth ||= Time.zone.today
  end

  def check_sensitive_fields
    return unless persisted?
    SENSITIVE_ATTRIBUTES.each do |attr|
      if object_value_matches_database_value?(attr)
        assign_attributes(attr => value_from_database(attr))
      end
    end
  end

  def object_value_matches_database_value?(attr)
    if new_record?
      raise "#{self.class.name} must be saved before #{attr} values can be checked."
    end
    masked(attr) == SensitiveValue.new(value_from_database(attr)).mask
  end

  def value_from_database(attr)
    self.class.find(id).send(attr)
  end

  def masked(attr)
    SensitiveValue.new(send(attr) || "").mask
  end

  def should_mask?(attr)
    persisted? and object_value_matches_database_value?(attr)
  end

  def masked_if_appropriate(attr)
    should_mask?(attr) ? masked(attr) : send(attr)
  end
end
```

Evidently the gem is loading just fine because the `attr_encryptor` call I'm doing is working just fine. For some reason the gem is just not functioning.

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Heroku and now it works. I thought Heroku automatically restarted when you do a deployment.